# Combine AngularUI Calendar with fullcalendar.io Scheduler

Tags: angularjs, fullcalendar

I am trying to combine https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-calendar with http://fullcalendar.io/scheduler/ the **Scheduler** is not AngularJs

When I add Scheduler.js

I get this error:

```
 FC.warn('v' + FC.schedulerVersion + ' of FullCalendar Scheduler ' + 'is incompatible with v' + FC.version + ' of the core.\n' + 'Please see http://fullcalendar.io/support/ for more information.');
```

Searching for an angular version was fruitless. 
The problem obviously is: they are not compatible.

Does anyone know of a solution (with AngularUi Calendar)?
Or am I forced to move to Jquery version of AngularUi Calendar?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have to use a different version of the fullcalendar core
[support fullcalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/support/) FullCalendar Core version >=3.4.0